# Mapping nested JSON object from api to json object

Tags: javascript, json

My api return a nested json object and I want to map it in json object in data in vue.

*My api response:*

[image: my api response]

I want to map it to:

```
editedItem:{
  FirstName: '',
  LastName: '',
  Address: '',        
  DepartmentName: '',
}
```

I just want to map the `DepartmentModel.DepartmentName` to `DepartmentName`.

This is how what I've done by the way.

*item contains*:

[image: item]

```
this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
```

Comment: what is a "nested JSON object" - it just looks like a regular javascript object, no JSON about it since it's not a String, it's an Object

Comment: Is `DepartmentModel` the only property that needs flattening or are there others? Are the properties known or could it be dynamic? How would you expect `Id` to be handled as that exists on both the outer and inner objects in your example? Or do you literally just want the 4 properties given in your example?